# How to get status of mail send by Mandrill java api?

Tags: java, mandrill

I have get an **Internal server exception** for getting mail information while using lutung's java API of mandrill. Here is my code.

```
public MandrillMessageInfo getMessageInfo(String id) {
MandrillApi mandrillApi = new MandrillApi("Your api key");
MandrillMessageInfo info = null;
try {
    info = mandrillApi.messages().info(id);
    log.debug("Message status-> Email {}, state: {}, timeOfSent: {} ", info.getEmail() ,info.getState(), TimeUtil.getLocalTimeString(info.getTs()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.debug("Exception occurs while getting message info for id: {}, exception is: {} ", id, e.getMessage());
    throw new MailServiceException(ErrorCodes.ERROR_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ErrorCodes.ERROR_MESSAGE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
} 
return info;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're throwing the Internal server exception yourself?

Comment: Yes . But **info()** method which i had called throws  **MandrillApiError** exception. My problem is that how i get info about sent mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong in your code. If your API key is right, the only reason this request will return an error is if you give a wrong id. You can verify that by issuing a messages/info api request directly on mandrill website using "Try It" button https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=info and pass the same message id, that you are giving via the program call.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you. The API key was correct but unfortunately message id was wrong.